# Hanoi's tower min moves

Tags: logic

Hello everyone how do you calculate hanoi's min moves for n Discs by mathematical induction I found by some tests that the general number should be `a_n=2^n-1` but i couldn't prove it for n+1 so i did some research and found `a_(n+1)=2a_n+1` why ?

Comment: For the three-peg tower of hanoi puzzle, to move the full tower of height $n+1$ from the left peg to the right peg you have no choice but to first move the top $n$ discs onto the middle peg, then move the largest disc to the right peg, then the tower of height $n$ from the middle peg to the right peg.  The action of moving the smaller tower is known to be possible by induction and requires $a_n$ moves.  Thus the total number of moves is $a_{n+1}=a_n+1+a_n=2a_n+1$.  Note the difference between this problem and the problem where there are four or more pegs.

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) $\ddot\smile$ you need to use it

Answer (score 2):

The proof that you *can* always solve the Towers of Hanoi problem with $n$ discs in $2^n-1$ moves is a simple inductive proof:

Base: $n=1$. Trivially, you can move the 1 disc in $2^1-1=1$ move

Step: Using the inductive hypotheses that you can move a stack of $n$ discs from one peg to another in $2^n-1$ moves, you can move $n+1$ discs from peg $A$ to peg $C$ by first moving the top stack of $n$ discs from $A$ to $B$ in $2^n-1$ moves, then moving the largest disc from $A$ to $C$, and then moving the stack of $n$ discs from $B$ to $C$ in $2^n-1$ moves, for a total of $2^n-1+1+2^n-1=2\cdot2^n-1=2^{n+1}-1$ moves.

The proof that this is the *minimum* amount of moves is almost the same:

Base: Clearly the minimum number of moves to move a stack of 1 disc from $A$ to $C$ is 1.

Step: The inductive hypotheses is that the minimum number of moves to move a stack of $n$ discs from one peg to another is $2^n-1$. Now, if you have a stack of $n+1$ discs, the only way for the larger disc to move from $A$ to $C$ is if the other discs are all on peg $B$. So, any solution will first have to move the top$n$ discs from $A$ to $C$, which takes a minimum of $2^n-1$ moves, then move the largest disc from $A$ to $C$, and then move the other $n$ discs from $B$ to $C$ for a minimum of $2^1-1$ moves, so the minimum number of moves to move all $n+1$ discs from $A$ to $C$ is $2^n-1+1+2^n-1=2\cdot2^n-1=2^{n+1}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't move the last disk unless you have all others on a different pole. By induction this will take you $2^n-1$ moves. Now $1$ more move to move the biggest disk to another pole and $2^n-1$ more moves to return the rest of the disk back. Hence the number is given by:

$$2^n - 1 + 1 + 2^n - 1= 2^{n+1} - 1$$